# iOS: How to use constraintsWithVisualFormat without someView.addConstraints?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I run into an issue where I have no clue how to use the old function `constraintsWithVisualFormat` without the `addConstraints` function on some specific view.

The header file says:

> This method will be deprecated in a future release and should be
>   avoided.  Instead use +[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:].

Ok I'm fine with class functions but do I misunderstand here something? I was fixing my issue with pure `AutoLayout` and `UIScrollView` ([Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)).

So I could do it like this and everything will be fine for now, but it won't be in the future:

```
let views = ["containerView" : self.containerView]

self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[containerView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[containerView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Does this approach not set the `firstItem` or `secondItem` of the `NSLayoutConstraint` under the hood?

How do I mimic the right VF for this example?

I know how to create the same constraints with the new anchor syntax, but I'm curios how to use VFL in the future!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `constraintsWithVisualFormat`. The header simply recommends that you replace `self.scrollView.addConstraints(...)` with `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(...)`.

```
let views = ["containerView" : self.containerView]

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[containerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[containerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Under the hood `[containerView]` is your container view, and `|` is the superview — these are the `firstItem` and `secondItem`.

Comment: I would up vote twice for `| is the superview`. Didn't know that the whole time. Thx a lot.

Comment: @vacawama I know how to use `activateConstraints` but my point was the superview which I thought was added  to the constraints by calling the old `addConstraints ` function on a specific view.